# DOM Exception: Invalid header name

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am getting error DomException:

> invalid header name my http.service.ts class is this.headers with
> basic auth and body with formdata.
> enter code here import '''{ HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import axios from 'axios';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthConstants } from '../config/auth-constants';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import * as process from 'process';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
storageService: any;
  router: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient,private toastCtrl: ToastController) {}

tokenpost(serviceName: string, data: any) {

  const formData = new FormData();
  const dataJson = {
    'username': data.username,
    'password': data.password,
    'grant_type': 'password'
  };
  console.log('dataJson:', dataJson);
  formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(dataJson));
  console.log('formData: ', formData.getAll('data'));

  const username = "mobile";
  const password = "pin";
  const encoded = btoa(username + ":" + password);

  const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept':  'application/json',
    'Authorization':'Basic${encoded}',
    ' Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

    })
  };

const proxyurl = "curl https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = environment.apiUrl + serviceName;
console.log(url);
return this.http.post(url, formData,httpOptions )

}
}'''
```

Comment: is it necessary to add cross origin allow access  in backend.